# How to use reflection to get just the object instance's public properties?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reflecting on an object and only want the public properties of an instance, I don't want public static properties.  The problem is `GetProperties()` returns both static and instance public properties.  Anyone have an idea how to best approach this problem?

```
private IOrderedEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetSortedPropInfos()
{
    return dataExtractor.GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(
            p => p.Name );
}
```

Note, I sort the list since `GetProperties()` does not specify any type of ordering, and ordering is important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private IOrderedEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetSortedPropInfos()
{
    return dataExtractor.GetType()
                        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                        .OrderBy( p => p.Name );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [the other overload of GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx), which allows you to specify *binding flags* such as `BindingFlags.Instance`.

```
return dataExtractor.GetType().GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).OrderBy(
        p => p.Name );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you need to set the binding flags in the constructor.  The binding flags specify flags that control binding and the way in which the search for members and types is conducted by reflection. Take a look at the following for more information:

**BindingFlags Enumeration:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out an addendum to the other answers -- also use `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` if you don't want inherited properties.