# How do I make this class an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created the following view model for an MVC application.  What I'd like to do is make it an `IEnumerable` class so that I can iterate through the data in my page using a `foreach` statement.

```
public class EstimateDetailsModel
{
    public string dma { get; set; }
    public string callsign { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

}
```

In case it's relevant, here is the corresponding Linq query in my repository that instantiates the `EstimatesDetailsModel` class:

```
public IEnumerable<EstimateDetailsModel> GetEstimateDetails(int id)
{
    var estimateDetails = from e in db.Estimates
                          join es in db.EstimateStations on e.EstimateID equals es.EstimateID
                          join s in db.Stations on es.StationID equals s.StationID
                          join m in db.Markets on s.MarketID equals m.MarketID
                          where e.EstimateID == 1
                          select new EstimateDetailsModel { dma = m.DmaName, callsign = s.CallSign, description = s.StationDescription };
    return estimateDetails;                                  
}
```

Comment: Could you show an example of how you want to use it? Do you mean have it iterate over the properties of the model?

Comment: What exactly you want to make IEnumerable? Properties of EstimateDetailsModel?

Comment: Everything looks fine. You should be able to iterate through the results of `GetEstimateDetails()` as is.

Comment: I want to pass EstimateDetailsModel to the view and then iterate through it with a foreach statement to generate a list.  The list would look like this DMA | CALLSIGN | DESCRIPTION.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
public class EstimateDetailsModel : IEnumerable<string>
{
    public string Dma { get; set; }

    public string Callsign { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return Dma;
        yield return Callsign;
        yield return Description;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

(I have capitalised the properties, which is the normal style.)

Comment: Didn't know you could just do a naked `yield return` in an `IEnumerator` method. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to do something like this?

```
public class EstimateDetailsModel: List<EstimateDetailsModel.EstimateDetail>
{
    public class EstimateDetail
    {
        public string dma { get; set; }
        public string callsign { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a property in the EstimateDetailsModel that exposes the EstimateDetails from the Repository?  Something like this, assuming you'd have a Repository reference in the Model:

```
public class EstimateDetailsModel
{
    public int EstimateID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<EstimateDetailsModel> EstimateDetails
    {
        return Repository.GetEstimateDetails(this.EstimateID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With reflection it's possible to automate the enumeration of any object's properties names and values (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556908/how-to-use-reflection-to-get-just-the-object-instances-public-properties), among [others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reflection+enumeration+properties+c%23&submit=search)). But it's sometimes overkill. I'm assuming you're interested in viewing `EstimateDetailsModel` as a dictionary. I suggest the following:

```
public class EstimateDetailsModel : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    public string Dma { get; set; }
    public string CallSign { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Dma", Dma);
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CallSign", CallSign);
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Description", Description);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```